# copying linux device files through rsync-daemon fails

Tags: linux, rsync

I can copy linux device files without any error this way:

```
rsync --recursive --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --xattrs --acls --stats /path/to/dev root@MACHINE:/path/to/bkps/
```

but I get a lot of errors of the kind

**skipping non-regular file "dev/audio"**

when I do it like this:

```
rsync --recursive --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials --xattrs --acls --stats /path/to/dev  rsync://root@MACHINE/MODULE/
```

where **rsync** on **MACHINE** is running in daemon-mode and its **rsyncd.conf** contains the following configs:

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
strict modes = true
uid = UID_TO_SET
gid = GID_TO_SET
read only = no
list = yes

[MODULE]
path = /path/to/bkps/
```

The only difference in the above commandlines is the destination path:

**root@MACHINE:/path/to/bkps/**

vs.

**rsync://root@MACHINE/MODULE/**

Can anybody help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The daemon and module must be uid root for `--owner` or `--devices` to work.  It's not clear from your `rsyncd.conf` what the value of `uid` and `gid` are.  Just because your user is named root doesn't mean the daemon or module are running with root privileges.

Additionally, you can replace the following args:

`--recursive --links --perms --times --group --owner --devices --specials`

with `-a` or `--archive`, which is an alias for all of those.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matt for his input, and after some more manual-reading and testing I could solve the problem:

- The UID and GID directives in rsyncd.conf specified unprivileged, "normal" users/groups indeed, because I thought these directives are to set the user/group of the copied data
- And as the rsync-daemon is started by the system on start-up, I thought it was running as root anyway